# How to pass a variable to put-item using AWS CLI dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to pass in a variable value to map Jarfile name in dynamoDB table using AWS CLI.

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name epis-deployment-history --item "{\"JarFile\":{\"S\":$JarFile}}"  --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

It threw this error. It substitutes the value correctly but the CLI commands fail to run.

Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 17 (char 16)
JSON received: {"JarFile":{"S":medallia-dealertrack-93311b0-20210301-133510.jar}}
Deploy to preprod Complete.

Thank you

Comment: Try enclosing `medallia-dealertrack-93311b0-20210301-133510.jar` in double quotes as well. Otherwise it's not valid JSON

Comment: Put quotes around the variable

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but that didn't work either. Got this Error parsing parameter '--item': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
JSON received: {[{"JarFile":{"S":"medallia-dealertrack-93311b0-20210301-133510.jar"}]}

Comment: aws dynamodb put-item --table-name epis-deployment-history --item "{[{\"JarFile\":{\"S\":\"$JarFile\"}]}" --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, but now for different reason. You cannot have `[]` immediately after curly brackets. Valid JSON would be: `{"JarFile":{"S":"medallia-dealertrack-93311b0-20210301-133510.jar"}}`